# Autofilling fields based on another field

Tags: 7, entities

I have a very complex situation where I need some advice. I have a content type `my_content`, which has a field collection field attached to it `field_mycollection`, which has an entity reference field referencing to user `field_my_userreference`, a phone field `field_my_phone`, a text field `field_my_text`, and another text field `field_my_anothertext`.

```
My Content
|_ field_mycollection
   |_ field_my_userreference
   |_ field_my_phone
   |_ field_my_text
   |_ field_my_anothertext
```

The user entity has also have fields `field_my_phone`, `field_my_text` and `field_my_yetanothertext` which the latter has a different machine name.

What I want to do, if in `my_content` edit/add form, in `field_my_userreference` a user is selected, the other fields should be auto-populated from the selected user's data. The auto-populated fields should still be editable.

How could I achieve this goal? I'd like to do it, if possible, with some coding, using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

Comment: Do you need it to happen live on form, or on save?

Comment: Live on form. I have already implemented it that on save, that the data will taken from user entity if left empty. But actually what I need it on form :(

Comment: OK, posed my answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you want it to happen live, and all fields are on the form already, safest way would be to use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to add following to a form:

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name') . '/js/copy_field_value.js',
);
```

Then in `copy_field_value.js` create behavior:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.moduleNameCopyFieldValue = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      // Repeat this for all fields as needed
      $('#source', context).on('blur', function () { 
        // above you can use change instead of blur if element is not changed by another js
        if (!$('#destination').val() || 0 === $('#destination').val().length) {
          $('#destination').val($(this).val());
          // wrap line above in "if no value" like I did, or other condition you like
        }
      });
      // end of "repeat this"
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

You can also use `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to add [`#ajax` parameter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) to source field, but it would make your form to call a server on each field copy. If you need to actually query database, it is the way to go. It would be pretty broad to describe it anew here. You need to alter `$form_state["input"]` array to update real values seen by user. Do it in form creation function, wrapping it with `isset` to avoid notices.

If your form element is `$form["something"]["something"]["element"]`, its value will be in `$form_state["input"]["something"]["something"]["element"]` - and you can set it in `hook_form_alter` all right, just remember to take both `$form` and `$form_state` by reference.

**Note**: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method was added in jQuery 1.7, so you will need [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) to use this answer directly, or translate my code to use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) or [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) method.

Comment: Many thanks for the instructions! I am not very well on Drupal's JS API. Would you explain how I get the field values from user entity? For example, if a user is selected, how can I populate the next fields with this user's info?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. the trick here is not to care about php background. Just identify ID parameters of `<input>` tags using Firebug or similar tool for your favourite browser. Or use any other jQuery selector. It will happen in browser only, so you have what you have on screen. On the other hand if you need to actually query database (seems I missed that), `#ajax` is the way to go. But it would be pretty broad. You need to alter `$form_state["values"]` array to update real values seen by user. Do it in form creation function, wrapping it with `isset` to avoid notices.

Comment: Thanks again @Mołot, I'll try to implement it tomorrow, or maybe this evening. It seems I will need a few hours to get it really work, if not more.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. good luck, feel free to return with more questions and link them here in comments if they are connected. Updated answer a bit, btw.

Comment: Ok, I'll experiment it a bit and I'll write my experiences.

Comment: I am having struggles with implementing #ajax parameter. I have opened a public chat room. Would you join and take a look when you have time? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10371/ajax-autopopulate-fields-from-another-entity Thanks.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. no sooner than in 3 hours, sorry :(

Comment: no problem. I have already explained it in the chat room in more details. Please check whenever you have time. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Mołot, very helpful. I've used the behavior method and it works perfect. I just needed to change $('#source', context).on('change', function(){ to $('#edit-started', context).change(function(){ Until then I've got the "object has no method 'on'" error. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using the [computed field module](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field)

> Computed Field is a very powerful CCK field module that lets you add a
>   custom "computed fields" to your content types. These computed fields
>   are populated with values that you define via PHP code. You may draw
>   on anything available to Drupal, including other fields, the current
>   user, database tables, you name it. (Feeling the power yet? :) ) You
>   can also choose whether to store your computed field values in the
>   database with other content fields, or have them "calculated" on the
>   fly during node views. (Although you should note that Views use
>   requires database stored values.) This field is literally the Swiss
>   Army knife of CCK fields. So start cooking up your PHP based values!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It sounds very promising. Though, I don't want to install a module for that but simply write some code, since I need such a functionality only on that form, and the actual system is already too big and many modules are installed for diverse functionalities.

Comment: Secondly, is it possible using this module, for the user who is creating or editing the node to override the auto-populated fields manually and save? So that, in the user entity and my_content are different values are saved.

Comment: That would depend on the way it is setup

Comment: Thanks @4life, I'll give that also a try if I can't achieve it with coding, using the instructions of Mołot.

Answer (score 2):

I want to post how I achieved it thanks to great helps of @Mołot.

1. Implemented the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7).
2. Added a wrapping div around the field collection.
3. Since the my field collection is a multi-value field, iterated over 
   it and set the `#ajax` property for the field `field_my_userreference`.
4. Created a callback function which simply returns the field collection item back.
5. Checked in the hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() implementation, if $form_state for the field collection is set. If yes, get the values from the user entity and populate the form input fields with those values.

My code looks like:

```
function MYMODULE_form_my_content_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['field_mycollection']['#prefix'] = '<div id="mycollection-wrapper">';
  $form['field_mycollection']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  foreach ($form['field_mycollection']['und'] as $key => $fc_mycollection) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
      $form['field_mycollection']['und'][$key]['field_my_userreference']['und']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'MYMODULE_mycollection_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'mycollection-wrapper',
      );
      if (isset($form_state['values']['field_mycollection']['und'][$key]['field_my_userreference']['und'][0]['target_id'])) {
        $user_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $form_state['values']['field_mycollection']['und'][$key]['field_my_userreference']['und'][0]['target_id']);
        $form_state['input']['field_mycollection']['und'][$key]['field_my_text']['und'][0]['value'] = $user_wrapper->field_my_text->value() ? $user_wrapper->field_my_text->value() : '';
        $form_state['input']['field_mycollection']['und'][$key]['field_my_anothertext']['und'][0]['value'] = $user_wrapper->field_my_text->value() ? $user_wrapper->field_my_yetanothertext->value() : '';
      }
    }
  }
}

function MYMODULE_mycollection_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['field_mycollection'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late but this module https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill, seems to do what you are describing. I have used it and it can help you as well.