# Add value to hidden field on submit

Tags: 8, hooks

I am trying to write a custom module in Drupal 8 to populate a taxonomy field (release_decade) based on information in another field (release_date) for a custom content type in order to create an exposed dropdown filter in a view.

I am using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter` & have tried attaching JS as suggested in [autofilling-fields-based-on-another-field](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83909/autofilling-fields-based-on-another-field) but the script does not seem to run & most of the other examples seem to cover Drupal 7.

Does anyone have any Drupal 8 specific suggestions for either:
a) Autofilling a taxonomy field based on other content fields?
b) Automatically assigning a taxonomy item to a hidden property when an entity is created?

Or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context? Is this a block plugin, or a form controller?

Comment: Also can you display some of your attempted code?

Comment: It seems like this is more JavaScript question than Drupal question.

Comment: None of the code I have attempted so far as actually had any effect & I am unsure if I am going about this in the right way. I am trying to use `function <module_name>_form_node_article_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)` to attach a Javascript file to a form. Is this possible?